# ListView minimal height cannot be changed

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a simple `ListView` in UWP. I want the list elements to have smaller height than the default height. It seems I can assign a higher value, but there is a minimum value for height that cannot be overridden.

I've tried setting negative padding and negative margins, lowering font size and alignment, but to no avail.

The following is the code I am using.

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" Margin="0,10,0,0" IsItemClickEnabled="False">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Element">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="10" Margin="0" Padding="0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0" Margin="0" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Setting the `StackPanel` height to lower values simply cuts off the text (or the text panel), but the item height remains the same. Setting to higher values increases the item height, though.

Does anyone have an explanation or a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution. Change the `ItemContainerStyle` and set the `MinHeight` property to the target value.

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="32"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```